# Wordpress PHP/Web.Config Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web-config, iis-8

I have installed and been able to use Wordpress on my server just fine.  I use IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2.  However, I am learning now I am having problems with how it is configured, which I found out because I was trying to update max upload size. I have no web.config, php.ini, .htaccess files I need in order to change it.

Most sites are saying to update and save permalinks and that will force creation but when I do that it is telling me “You should update your web.config now”. I tried to manually create php.ini, .htaccess, and web.config files and placed them at various levels individually to test to see if they were picking up but weren't.  Any suggestions how to proceed? I've been stuck on this for a week and have ran out of pages of Google to click on.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://solutions.hostmysite.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/8793/278/wordpress-webconfig-file-for-windows) article, for IIS you need to create a *web.config* file in a root folder. The article shows the default code for WordPress. Try to use that code.

Regarding the update **max upload size**, you need to edit *php.ini* file where the PHP is installed in your system. Inside the *php.ini*, locate the **upload_max_filesize** option and set the size to the one you want. Once the change is saved, restart the server.